# How to crawl start URLs only?

Tags: scrapy

I'm trying to make the spider crawl just the provided start URLs without following any extracted links. I've tried setting `rules = (Rule (follow=False),)` but it still follows links. Does anyone know how to download the start URLs only?

EDIT:

Here's some code

```py
class Spider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'spider'
    user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'

    def __init__(self, mode, *args, **kwargs):
        if mode == 'scan':
            self.start_urls = ['https://www.example.com/']
            self.rules = (Rule (callback="parse_obj", follow=False),
                        )                   
                            
            self.custom_settings = {
                                'COMPRESSION_ENABLED': True,
                                'URLLENGTH_LIMIT': 100,
                                'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 1
                            }          
        elif mode == 'crawl':
            # something else

        super(Spider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: You don't have to use rules. If you can share your code we can help better.

Comment: Only scraping the start_urls is scrapy's default behaviour

Comment: You're right. Without rules set, it only scrapes `start_urls`. But with `rules` set as above, it scrapes other links as well though. I need to set a `callback` though.

Comment: @skyriver I've attached some code now.

Comment: @Alexander I need the call back to parse the content and generate items from the start URLs. This is basically my code, except for `parse_obj` which is very much uninteresting right now. My spider is extending `CrawlSpider` so I can't override `parse`. For some `mode` arguments, I'd need to crawl other links, but for some arguments it should just parse the start URLs. Also I'm trying to invoke different parse functions for different `mode` arguments.

Comment: @Alexander Like I said in my last comment, I'm trying to make the spider take on different behaviours for different `mode` arguments. For `scan`, it only parses the start URLs, but for something like `crawl` it crawls everything.

Comment: I see now... why try to cram so much functionality into one spider?  Just have each mode represent a different spider?

Comment: @Alexander Sure. That'd certainly solve my problem. I just find it unintuitive that a blank rule with a callback set would change the crawling behaviour.

Comment: @JohnM.  It isn't all that unintuitive when you consider that you are trying to suppress the the Crawl part of the CrawlSpider.... If you think about it from the scrapy teams point of view, if don't want to crawl the site then you wouldn't use the crawl spider. however I see your point and i am sure if you really wanted to there is some way to make it work, but it would probably be more complex and convoluted than it's worth

Comment: @Alexander I'll keep it simple and just make separate spiders. Thanks.